# How to put a formula into a cell by Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to put this  `=IF(D49>0,D49-D50-D51+D52+D53,)` into a cell `D54` by using macro.

My code is as follow

```
Range("D54").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(D52>0,D49-D50-D51+D52+D53,)"
```

But when I run the macro.

Cell `D54` gets this `=IF('D52'>0,'D49'-'D50'-'D51'+'D52'+'D53',)` instead.

Excel adds quotation marks to each dells in the formula, render the formula useless. How can I get macro to into formula as formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having issues because you are using the R1C1 formula property for your range, yet you are using classical cell references in your formula. You should be using the `Range("D54").Formula` property. So your code would look like:

```
Range("D54").Formula = "=IF(D52>0,D49-D50-D51+D52+D53,)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `Range("D54").Value = "=IF(D52>0,D49-D50-D51+D52+D53,)"`

I have used that method before and hand good results with it.

Comment: That's that worked. But is that how formula in Excel macro suppose to be done?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is they way the it was intended to be done, but if it works without any problems (and I've not encountered any to date), I see no reason why there can't be more than one solution to a problem.